# I can FTP with my Browser and Cyberduck but not Filezilla

Tags: ftp, filezilla, cyberduck

I have seen different topics with variations on this question but so far I was not able to resolve the problem. I am able to FTP via Firefox, Safari and Cyberduck but when attempting the same with FileZilla I get the following error:

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.url.co.uk
Status: Connecting to IPADDRESS:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220-Welcome To Rumpus!
Response:   220 Service ready for new user
Command:    USER EE
Response:   331 Password required
Command:    PASS ***********
Response:   530 Login failed
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Is this a FileZilla/Firewall problem? Why can I do it so easily via other clients?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked whether you are in active or passive mode? Also obviously triple check username and password.

Comment: There is no file transfer or directory listing yet, so passive/active does not matter. Also, it clearly says "530 Login failed" which means, that either the username or the password or both are wrong. Are you sure, that the username should be upper case ?

Answer (score 2):

Hey I fixed the issue by reinstalling everything. Really weird....Thanks.